# Function to take rows of two matrices in R like Map

Tags: r

I have two matrices say `A` and `B`. I want to take corresponding rows of both `A` and `B` and perform some computations. I tried both `Map` and `mapply`, but without success. I can do this using `for` loop, but I want to know is there any other function in `R` which works on row or column values of `n` matrices.

Here I am providing two matrices

```
# A<- dput(SAS[1:5,1:3])
A <- structure(c(1, 0.752883144886123, 0.665820582687678, 0.332066199562453, 
0.298438041926883, 1, 0.874502944276854, 0.802056449299557, 0.523826654155693, 
0.464779293591712, 1, 0.987890530841308, 0.906426596434083, 0.825898519791539, 
0.584637768405933), .Dim = c(5L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("4", "5", "6")))
# B<- dput(IND[1:5,1:3])
B <- structure(c(20L, 22L, 21L, 13L, 10L, 20L, 22L, 21L, 13L, 10L, 
20L, 22L, 13L, 21L, 15L), .Dim = c(5L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("4", "5", "6")))
```

**UPDATE**
Say I want to find the greatest corresponding element in each row of two matries
.I used Map, but this is not working

```
Map(function(x,y){g1 <- sort(x, decreasing=TRUE)[1] 
                  g2 <- sort(y, decreasing=TRUE)[1]
                 },A,B)
```

Expected output:

```
1   |20
0.98|22
0.9 |21
0.8 |21
0.5 |15
```

Comment: Please share attempts and expected output.

Comment: updated my question with expected output

Comment: Sorry, I copied this code. Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
t(mapply(function(x,y) c(max(x), max(y)),
           split(A, row(A)), split(B, row(B))))
#       [,1] [,2]
#1 1.0000000   20
#2 0.9878905   22
#3 0.9064266   21
#4 0.8258985   21
#5 0.5846378   15
```

---

Or we can use `rowMaxs` from `library(matrixStats)`

```
library(matrixStats)
sapply(list(A,B), rowMaxs)
#          [,1] [,2]
#[1,] 1.0000000   20
#[2,] 0.9878905   22
#[3,] 0.9064266   21
#[4,] 0.8258985   21
#[5,] 0.5846378   15
```

Or using `pmax` from `base R`

```
sapply(list(A,B), function(x) do.call(pmax, as.data.frame(x)))
```